# How to use PJSIP library with CMake?

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, pjsip

I know how the basic `Makefile` for a simple project using `pjsip` library [looks like](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting_Started_Using). But what does the equivalent `CMake` file look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
project(myapp)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)

include (FindPkgConfig)
if (PKG_CONFIG_FOUND) # true if pkg-config works on the system
  pkg_check_modules(PJSIP REQUIRED libpjproject)
endif()

include_directories(${PJSIP_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PJSIP_LIBRARY_DIRS})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PJSIP_LIBRARIES})
```